# Javascript build a string from the length of an array of ?,

Tags: javascript

Is there a pretty way of building a string of something like (?,?,?) for the number of items in an array

I've tried

```
values.map(() => '?,')
values.reduce((a,b) => {a + '?,'},'')
```

but both are not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map question marks for each element and join the array in an template literal.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    string = `(${array.map(_ => '?').join()})`;
    
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  "(" + values.map(el => "?").join() + ")"
```

You could just `join` them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from map and reduce functions.

```
var valuse = [1,2,3]
var newValues = values.reduce((a,b) => a === '' ? '?' : a + ',?','');
console.log(newValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the arrays forEach() extension, like this:

```
var string = "";
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].forEach((elem, index) => string += "?");
```